# How to get a developer key for ViaGogo API

Tags: c#

Long shot, but I'd like to fiddle with ViaGogo API (C# library more precisely). ViaGogo has a well documented public API, [documentation is avaliable here](http://developer.viagogo.net/#authentication).

Problem is, you need to authenticated as it usually happens with this kind of APIs: usually, you find a section of the website, maybe in your profile section, where you can obtain keys, secrets and so on (this happens for example on Facebook or Amazon).

As for ViaGogo, I only found a link that points to a [Google Form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScIJXd3dqjhCjnANkU6sNK4SLmcUSRWH4tTZyvUyGWZWgT0Uw/viewform?c=0&w=1): this form asks for info about advertising and affiliation on a complete different level of what I need, I won't publish anything read via API. Furthermore, there's no field to leave an e-mail address.

Their C# library seems pretty popular as far as I can tell from downloads from NuGet; I wonder how all these thousands of devs succesfully called that API.

Has anyone succesfully obtained authentication info from ViaGogo?

Comment: Reading the Google Form you posted, seems that you shoul fill the form and wait for a response in a 30 days limit. "Please note that due to the very high volume of applications we receive, we cannot respond to each individual query. In case you have not received a reply within 30 days, unfortunately you may have not been eligible."

Comment: Could be like that, but I can't understand the point of publishing an API while barring developers. I mean, the affiliate program is something focused on other things (advertising, selling tickets); I just need to pull data about my listings to move their management to a desktop application instead of their web interface. Probably it's the same procedure to follow, I just find it cumbersome for my kind of use (while I understand a serious scrutiny is needed if you want to affiliate with them).

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't seem to be any way around this registration according to their website and the api itself -- an appID and password is required. You may try your luck emailing them at Affiliate.Team@viagogo.com -- see this issue on github where the possibility of getting an account via email is discussed: https://github.com/viagogo/developer.viagogo.net/issues/24

Answer (score 2):

According to note in registration form, you have to wait for 30 days for their reply.
For more help you can contact them on following contacts:
E-mail:  affiliate@viagogo.com
Telephone:  +442075532777
Or
http://www.viagogo.com/in/help

Comment: Thank you for your effort (also @gregory); I was hoping for something more reliable but it's their fault not providing a direct way to get developer access info.